# Huge amount of data graphical representation

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame (ncols = 500, nrows = 14000).
It looks like this:

> ```
>           Sample1   Sample2   Sample3    .....    
> Gene1       22         0        0.11     .....    
> Gene2      0.112      0.1       0.4      .....     
> Gene3      0.45        0        0.19     .....    
> .....      .....     .....     .....     .....
> ```

I would like to plot such huge amount of data without applying any statistic so that it will be clear (simply using colors or other tools) the difference in terms of of numbers (magnitude) for ex. between Gene1 and Gene2 for Sample 1 and so on. 
Any idea apart from heatmap?

Comment: Try cluster with heatmap - [How to draw a Heat map for gene expression data?](http://www.biostars.org/p/8829/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `geom_raster` from ggplot2?

```
#  Make up some data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( matrix( runif(25) , 5 , 5 ) )
#         X1        X2         X3         X4         X5
#1 0.5316382 0.4360309 0.09576886 0.56497254 0.43930824
#2 0.2383700 0.1531009 0.71377161 0.39367645 0.42211072
#3 0.5009796 0.6549886 0.05996069 0.08236798 0.08574704
#4 0.1171437 0.8765644 0.29892712 0.06071803 0.78011966
#5 0.5066046 0.5486397 0.34770099 0.07785835 0.09659246

#  Abs difference between columns of dataframe
out <- data.frame( t( apply( df , 1 , function(x) abs( diff( x ) ) ) ) )

#  Plot using geom_raster    
require( ggplot2 )
require( reshape2 )
out.melt <- melt( out )
out.melt$y <- rep( 1:10,times = 9 )
p <- ggplot( out.melt , aes( variable , y , fill = value ) ) + geom_raster()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Simon! It works well!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the question was about truly huge data (e.g., when the number of data points is by far greater than the number of pixels on your screen), how about Bin-summarise-smooth: a framework for visualising large data, as described here http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/bigvis.html

```
@Article{bigvis,
  title = {Bin-summarise-smooth: a framework for visualising large data},
  author = {Hadley Wickham},
  year = {Submitted},
  journal = {Infovis 2013},
}
```

See also (e.g., the 5th slide of) this presentation  http://files.meetup.com/2906882/visualising_big_data_in_R.pdf

Comment: Hi knot! It is not exactly a problem of pixels, but a problem of meaningful  representation if possible, given the huge amount of numbers..